# Permission Denied when performing mySQL backup with mysqldump

Tags: python, mysql, permissions

I am using mysql with Python 3.5 on a Mac. When I attempt to use mysqldump to backup my database from the terminal command line I get a Permission Denied error message. Here is the command I am running from the terminal prompt:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p BIO > db_backup.sql
```

I have also tried the same process including my password:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -pmypassword BIO > db_backup.sql
```

but I still get the same error message. I have tried putting a space between -p and my password as well as putting no space between -p and my password and still get the same error. I've looked through all the search topics I could find on the topic but nothing seems applicable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the exact, actual error you get? This could be related to where you're trying to create `db_backup.sql`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. My actual error message is: -bash: db_backup.sql: Permission denied

Comment: It's not a MySQL problem, it's that you're not allowed to create files in that directory. Try `> /tmp/db_backup.sql` or `> ~/db_backup.sql` to save it somewhere you should be able to write to. Check that `db_backup.sql` doesn't already exist.

Comment: I tried this: $ sudo mysqldump -u root -p BIO > /tmp/db_backup.sql 
Password:
Enter password: 
      For some reason I was prompted twice for my password and the got the following error message:  mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: First just try `touch db_backup.sql` to see if you can create it. `sudo` is a wild tangent here. Change one thing at a time.

Comment: I tried the touch command and got the following error:  touch: db_backup.sql: Permission denied

Comment: Where are you trying to create this file? You'll need to be in a directory that's writable by your current user, like your home directory, and if that's not writable then you should fix those permissions before trying anything else.

Comment: This is the message I get when I try mysqldump without sudo. Obviously I was asked my password twice because of sudo, just took a sec to catch that.    mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: Hi, I am in my home directory when I execute this command. This is my machine and I have full permissions.

Comment: Try `touch example.sql` or something. Check with `ls -l db_backup.sql` to see if that file already exists and is owned by some other user. If you can't touch a simple file in your home directory you've got permission problems.

Comment: ls: db_backup.sql: No such file or directory is what I get when I run the ls command.

Comment: This is what I get when I run the touch command    touch: example.sql: Permission denied

Comment: If you can't create a file, your directory permissions are seriously wrong, so you may need to use Disk Utility and Repair Permissions to fix them. All `touch` does is try and create a zero-byte file or update the last modified time to now on any arbitrary file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with touch, is that a file creation command?

Comment: `man touch` has all the answers to your inquiry.

Comment: I just pulled up disk utility but I don't see a Repair Permissions button/tab. Can you provide me with some directions on how to repair the permissions?

Comment: I just did a google search and am going to try to run first aid in disk utility, repair permissions does not appear to be an option.

Comment: Apparently Disk Utility no longer repairs permissions. "Beginning with OS X El Capitan, system file permissions are automatically protected. It's no longer necessary to verify or repair permissions with Disk Utility." Is what the Apple support page says. After running Disk Utility - First Aid the program indicated my hard drive is fine. But the touch command still gives a permission denied error.

Comment: I went to my permissions menu and reset my permissions and now I can use the touch command without generating an error messaqe.

Comment: So now it appears I caqn make files but I am still getting an error message. The message has changed and is now   mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Comment: Looks like you're getting somewhere, that's an authentication issue. Problem #1 with permissions resolved.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you tadman, I really appreciate your help. I just got past the 1045 error and am now getting an 1146 error. I'll keep working on it but you were definitely correct to point me in the direction of fixing permissions. Thanks Again, George

Answer (score 0):

whenever you get a permission denied, repeat the command with `sudo` prepended.

```
 $ sudo mysqldump -u root -p BIO > db_backup.sql
```

Comment: This is a heavy-handed approach that can get you into trouble.

Comment: Hi, I tried prepending sudo but got the same error message

Comment: can you try saving the file somewhere else? Say home directory, see if it works,